# apply function using 2 columns in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

please consider the below "exampleDF".

```
name age    sex
a    21     male
b    13   female
c    56     female
d    12     male
e    45     nan
f    10     female
```

I want to create a new column using age and sex, so if age < 15 `newColumn` is `child` else its equal to sex.

I have tried this

```
exampleDF['newColumn'] = exampleDF[['age','sex']].apply(lambda age,sex: 'child' if age < 15 else sex)
```

but I get an error `missing 1 required positional argument: 'sex'`

Please help me with what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
import pandas as pd
exampleDF=pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','b','c','d','e','f'],'age':[21,13,56,12,45,10],'sex':['male','female','female','male',None,'male']})
exampleDF['newColumn'] = exampleDF[['age','sex']].apply(lambda x: 'child' if x['age'] < 15 else x['sex'],axis=1)
```

Then `exampleDF` is:

```
    age name    sex     newColumn
0   21  a       male    male
1   13  b       female  child
2   56  c       female  female
3   12  d       male    child
4   45  e       None    None
5   10  f       male    child
```

In your code you try to define `lambda age,sex:`, but you can't do that as `exampleDF[['age','sex']]` is one dataframe with two columns (and not two separate columns). The solution above resolves this issue. In addition, you also need to specify the axis.

Comment: this may be a very dumb question but when does `axis = 1` need to be specified? I have previously used apply function with lambda without specifying the axis.

Comment: By default axis=0, so you apply the function on the rows (see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), and I assume that this is what you wanted previously. However, here you want to apply it on the two columns x['age'] and x['sex'], so you need to specify axis=1.

Comment: Continuing my previous comment, here are two examples: The first one is exampleDF['newColumn'] = exampleDF[['age']].apply(lambda x: x**2). Here you just apply the square action on each element in  exampleDF[['age']], so you dont need to specify axis=1. However, in the following example: exampleDF['newColumn'] = exampleDF[['age']].apply(lambda x: True if x['age']>15 else False,axis=1) you need to use axis=1 as the function is applied on the entire column directly.

Answer (score 3):

I think better is use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) - if `True` in `boolean mask` get value from `sex` column else get `child` string to new column:

```
print (exampleDF['age'] < 15)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
Name: age, dtype: bool


exampleDF['newColumn'] = exampleDF['sex'].mask(exampleDF['age'] < 15, 'child')
print (exampleDF)
  name  age     sex newColumn
0    a   21    male      male
1    b   13  female     child
2    c   56  female    female
3    d   12    male     child
4    e   45     NaN       NaN
5    f   10  female     child
```

Main advantage of solution is it is faster:

```
#small 6 rows df
In [63]: %timeit exampleDF['sex'].mask(exampleDF['age'] < 15, 'child')
1000 loops, best of 3: 517 µs per loop

In [64]: %timeit exampleDF[['age','sex']].apply(lambda x: 'child' if x['age'] < 15 else x['sex'],axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 867 µs per loop
```

---

```
#bigger 6k df
exampleDF = pd.concat([exampleDF]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [66]: %timeit exampleDF['sex'].mask(exampleDF['age'] < 15, 'child')
The slowest run took 5.41 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 589 µs per loop

In [67]: %timeit exampleDF[['age','sex']].apply(lambda x: 'child' if x['age'] < 15 else x['sex'],axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 104 ms per loop
```

---

```
#bigger 60k df - apply very slow
exampleDF = pd.concat([exampleDF]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [69]: %timeit exampleDF['sex'].mask(exampleDF['age'] < 15, 'child')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 ms per loop

In [70]: %timeit exampleDF[['age','sex']].apply(lambda x: 'child' if x['age'] < 15 else x['sex'],axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.03 s per loop
```